# Help identifying frost free faucet make and model

Tags: plumbing, faucet

The plastic collar in the image below is cracked and needs replaced.  Does anyone know what make of faucet this is so i can track down parts. The knob has remnant of blue paint on it.

[image]

Comment: the knob tells us noting, keep looking for some kind of marker

Comment: There are **multiple duplicate questions** with much better pictures, some good enough that someone could actually sort it out. This picture, well, you can see it's a frost free sillcock, but there's no detail to help with what one it might be. The usual advice is to take it to a plumbing supply, or replace the whole thing. If you only shop at big-box stores, replace is really it. A decent plumbing supply will most likely be able to get you parts.

Comment: Blue colour on a knob just means it should be used on/for cold water line, but works just as well on the hot(red) water taps.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to identify the manufacturer will be near impossible from the pictures you provided. Your best bet would be to bring the old one into your home store or better yet, a plumbing supply store, and have them try to identify replacement parts. You could also try any local stores because they might have supplied the original to the builders and would have parts.  Honestly, I would just replace the the old one with a new one and since you've already removed it, half the work is done.